# Make select default option from database

Tags: php, html

i have issue with making default text in my select. (option list). So, my option is storage in database. Like `varchar` `Test Option`

Now if i make like this in my code

```
 <select  name="category">  <option  selected="selected"><?=$ad['category']?></option> <?php echo $options; ?> </select>
```

it working, but in my list be two same values then.
my full code.

```
              <?php

                while($category = mysqli_fetch_array($q)):;

                 ?>

              <option> value="<?php echo $category[0];?>" <?php echo $category[1];?> </option>"

               <?php endwhile; ?>


                

               <select  name="category">  <option  selected="selected"><?=$ad['category']?></option> <?php echo $options; ?> </select>
                
 
<?php
```

My code for function q and pick value from database (all value from option is from database)

```
   $q2 = mysqli_query($con,$q22222);
    $options = "";
     while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($q2))
     {
         $options = $options."<option>$row2[1]</option>";
     }
```

picture what explain situation more.
[image]

any idea how to solve it ? all help will be appreciated

Comment: Does the content from the pick list come from two different sources? Are `$q` and `$q2` just revisions of the same code? Where does the selected value come from, is it user input?

Comment: Your code appears to make rather little sense to begin with - you output a couple of `<option>…</option>` in a loop first, and then directly after that comes a `<select>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the real situation is that you are fetching an array but you want that the  option won't be printed. Then, you first have the selected option, that is:

```
<?php $ad['category']; ?>
```

Then the only thing that you have to do is that when you fetch the array, if the option is equal to the selected option won't be printed so:

```
   $q2 = mysqli_query($con,$q22222);
    $options = "";
     while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($q2))
     {
         if($row2[1]!=$selected){
              $options = $options."<option>$row2[1]</option>";
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to fetch same options again from the database you could use an `SELECT DISTINCT` statement in your select query.

And also handle the situation where the option is not same with the default one you chose.

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($q2))
{
    if($row2[1] != $selected) $options = $options."<option>$row2[1]</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select >
    <option value="1" <?php if ($Defaultselection == 1) echo "selected"; ?>>A</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ($Defaultselection == 2) echo "selected"; ?>>B</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($Defaultselection == 3) echo "selected"; ?>>C</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if ($Defaultselection == 4) echo "selected"; ?>>D</option>
</select>
```

Try it